# How to convert 2D array to 1D in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation

So for example I have a 2D array A={{1,2,3}, {2,3},{5}}; and I want to get all the rows existing in the array A. I have the length of array stored in variable "lenA", here lenA=3. Also I have an Array B which has the length of each subarray in A. Say B={3,2,1} in this case. In reference to my example array A, how to I dynamically get 3 subarrays from one 2D array i.e. A?
So as a result I would have something like:

```
A1={1,2,3}
A2={2,3}
A3={5}
```

Comment: Ok, I thought as much, thanks for clarifying. But that's what you already have, isn't it?

Comment: No, I have the 2D array. Have to get the subarrays stored at each index into a new array variable (new memory location), and these subarrays are to be named dynamically using a for loop. Can't figure out how to allocate memory locations and the names dynamically.

Comment: Variable names (and variables themselves) cannot be allocated dynamically in C++. Sometimes a `std::map` does what people want when they make requests like yours. You can use a string as the key to your map and use that key to retrieve your dynamically allocated arrays.

Comment: How is `A` defined? If the rows have different lengths, then it probably is a `int**` or `int*[]`? Then you already have what you want. Showing some code would help to clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

You can't dynamically generate new identifiers in C++.  The closest you can get is using the preprocessor to generate your names, and by definition, that's done before compilation.

If you already have a fixed number of named array pointers, you could assign those dynamically.  But any solution that must accept an arbitrary number of rows at runtime will require that you use something like an array index.

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < lenA; i++)
{
    // Do something with the row at A[i]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code

```
for i in 0 to lenA-1
    for j in 0 to lenB[i]-1
        A[i][j] whatever...
```

Answer (score 0):

My try converting A(4x4) to triangle *a[4]:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
int main()
{
   constexpr int lenA = 4;
   double A[lenA][lenA]={{1,2,3,4}, {5,6, 7, 0}, {8, 9,0,0},{10,0,0,0}};
   double *a[lenA];
   int B[lenA] = {4, 3, 2, 1};

   for (int i=0; i < lenA; i++)
    {
       a[i] = new double [ B[i] ];
       std::copy_n(A[i], B[i], a[i]);
    }
   for (int i=0; i<lenA; i++) {
       std::cout << "row " << i << ": ";
       for (int j=0; j<B[i]; j++) {
           std::cout << a[i][j] << ".  ";
           }
       std::cout <<std::endl;
      }
   return 0;
}
```

result:

```
$ ./a.exe
 row 0: 1.  2.  3.  4.
 row 1: 5.  6.  7.
 row 2: 8.  9.
 row 3: 10.
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find the verification of the below code at http://cpp.sh/57pi2

`A1D` represent the 1-Dimensional array which you was looking for,

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const int lenA = 4;
    double A2D[][lenA]={{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7},{8,9},{10}};
    double *A1D;
    int B[lenA] = {4,3,2,1};

    int num_of_elements = 0; 
    for (int i=0; i < lenA; i++)
        num_of_elements += B[i];
    
    A1D = new double[num_of_elements]   ; 
    for (int i=0, k=0; i<lenA; i++) 
        for (int j=0; j<B[i]; j++)
            A1D[k++] = A2D[i][j];

    for (int j=0; j<num_of_elements; j++)
        std::cout << A1D[j] << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::ranges` in `C++20` or [ranges library](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) (`C++14` compliant) does it in clean way:

```cpp
    double A[][4] {
        { 1, 2, 3, 4}, 
        { 5, 6, 7, 0}, 
        { 8, 9, 0, 0},
        {10, 0, 0, 0}
    };
    for (auto x : std::ranges::views::join(A))
        std::cout << x << '\n';
```

https://godbolt.org/z/hPP7e9